# Concise Optional unwrapping

Tags: swift, option-type

I am in the process of learning Swift, I have been experimenting with `Optional` unwrapping and came across this situation:

```
let displayText: String?

if let item = displayText {
    if let value = Double(item) {
        print("\(value)")
    } else {
        print("Didn't happen")
    }
} else {
    print("Didn't happen")
}
```

It seems something like this could be possible:

```
let displayText: String?

if let item = Double(displayText) {
    print("\(item)")
} else {
    print("Didn't happen")
}
```

In my case `displayText` might be `nil`, so force unwrapping is not what I want to do. I know I could hide this in a function to make it more concise, but I am really curious if there are other options.
Is there anyway to make this more concise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few possibilities:

#1: The General. You can put multiple unwrapping variable declarations on one line.

```
if let item = displayText, value = Double(item) {
    print("\(value)")
}
```

#2: The Hack. In your specific case, you can also default the empty optional to something you know isn't going to be a valid string representation of a Double:

```
if let value = Double(item ?? "") {
    print("\(value)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use `map` on Optionals:

```
if let value = displayText.map({ Double($0) }) {
    print("\(value)")
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about map, interesting, will have to read more about this.